# Is Zstd/Zlib compression bijective?

Tags: zlib, zstd

This is more of a conceptual question, but if I have a File A and a File B, 
is it possible for Compressed(A) to equal Compressed(B) if A != B. Additionally, if the compressed representations of A and B match, are A and B guaranteed to match?

Comment: No, if the compressed images match for different A and B, that would be "lossy" compression. The question can compressed representations of A and B match, but A and B not, is exactly the same question.

Comment: If this were possible, then decompression of either would result in the same thing, which could be A, B or something else.

Comment: So Zstd and Zlib are both bijective? Therefore I I simply want to tell if A != B, I don't have to decompress?

Comment: No, A could have been compressed with different versions of the library, or different compression levels, which would make compressed(A) != compressed(A).

However, if compressed(A) == compressed(B) then A == B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question seems not about bijection.

These algorithms would *maybe* be bijective if, for a given `File A`, there would be one and only one `Compressed(A)` possible.

It's obviously not the case : just play with the compression levels, you have multiple different versions of `Compressed(A)` which decompress back to the same `File A`. So it's not a [bijection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection).

However, the other direction is guaranteed : a given `Compressed(something)` can regenerate one and only one `something`. And since the compression is lossless, it guarantees that if `Compressed(A) == Compressed(B)`, then necessarily `A == B`.

But don't confuse that with bijection. When `A == B`, it doesn't follow that `Compressed(A) == Compressed(B)`, as they may have been compressed differently (using different compression levels or other advanced parameters).

Comment: But if the parameters same, then `Compressed(A) == Compressed(B)`? Arguing that different parameters could've been used is, from a mathematical pov, the same as saying `Compressed` isn't the same.

Comment: The original question was about a bijection.
Bijection implies a lot more than `if Compressed(A) == Compressed(B) then A == B`. A bijection also implies that `if Compressed(A) != Compressed(B) then A != B necessarily`.
And that's not the case for most (if not all) compression formats: multiple different `Compressed(A)` can exist, and would all map back to the same `A`.
This operation is more accurately described as a surjection.